# Find stale installed programs with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, uninstall, file-search

Is there an easier way to find stale installed programs with PowerShell than recursively visiting each sub-folder of Program Files for the newest access date?

It seems this is such a basic common need, there should be a simpler command than having to recursively get-childitem in and compare all the file dates.

Comment: sorry, after posting my answer, i saw the word "stale" in your question. I don't really get that word as a non native speaker, I hope my answer still works for your needs :-). If you want to find installed software, and not portable software, my answer should work.

Comment: The question is what qualifies as _stale_ anyway. Software that wasn’t recently used? I don’t think there’s a reliable way to find out.

Comment: Stale means old, as in hasn't been used for a long time, like if I haven't used something for years and I need to free disk space and other resources then there's probably no need to keep it. I am tempted to traverse the subdirectories looking for the latest access time for files under each program name if there's no better way.

Comment: from what i can tell, win10 & win11 _do not track that info_. [*sigh ...*] your workaround seems to be the closest approximation - and it is likely to be rather unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways: Registry query or via CIM/WMI (you can search for "list installed software powershell" [the first link already tells you this.](https://bobcares.com/blog/powershell-list-installed-software/)).

The CIM/WMI way works like this:

```
# Local Machine:
Get-CimInstance Win32_Product 

# Remote Machine:
$CimSession = New-CimSession Servername -Credential (Get-Credential)
Get-CimInstance Win32_Product -CimSession $CimSession

# Pipe to Where-Object to Filter vendors, or names etc.
Get-CimInstance Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Vendor -eq 'SomeVendor'}
```

However I personally always query the registry. You need to query the following keys to get both 32-bit and 64-bit applications:

- `HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
- `HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

I wrote a function for that that I always use. See below.

Usage:

```
# Lists all installed Programs
Get-InstalledSoftware

# List only software that matches a filter
Get-InstalledSoftware *firefox*

# List software that matches a filter and return all properties
Get-InstalledSoftware *firefox* -properties *

# Do the same on remote machines
Get-InstalledSoftware -ComputerName ServerA, ServerB -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Here's the function:

```
function Get-InstalledSoftware {
    
    param (
        # filters displayname of installed apps to search for
        [string]$filter = '*', 
        # tell the function what properties should be returned
        [string[]]$properties = @("DisplayName","InstallDate","InstallLocation"), 
        # remote computername(s)
        [string[]]$ComputerName,
        # credential for remote computer(s)
        [pscredential]$Credential
    )

    # reg paths to query
    $regpath = @(
        "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*",
        "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
    )

    # put together the splat for remote usage of function
    $splat = @{}
    if ($ComputerName) { $splat['ComputerName'] = $ComputerName }
    if ($Credential) { $splat['Credential'] = $Credential }

    # Run the command, either locally or remote if $splat has values
    Invoke-Command @splat -ScriptBlock { 
        param ($regpath, $filter, $properties)
        $regpath | ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty $_ } | 
        Where-Object { ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.DisplayName) -and $_.DisplayName -like $filter } | 
        Select-Object $properties 
    } -ArgumentList $regpath, $filter, $properties
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Good try. I can do that to see what's installed but it doesn't tell how long since it's been used.